# Get the number of past/remaining events for a recurring event

Tags: applications, calendar, app-widgets

Let's say I created a recurring event in my calendar, e.g. start begin of this year, end is end of this year, running every Monday evening at 18:00

Does anybody know a possibility to get information for the current day like

- 20 events had been finished
- 32 events are still remaining

Of course, it would work only with appointments having a start and an end date.

I found a lot of countdown apps, however they are counting the number of years/months/days/etc. till a specific event will happen. They don't count the number of remaining recurring events.